# layout edittext cast webview

Tags: android, android-layout

I would create this Layout :

[WEBVIEW]

[EDITTEXT][BUTTON]

This is my layout code 
First I declare a layout with width and height : fill_parent
After I declare a layout for the webview
And finally, I declare a layout for the EditText and the button :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#3b3b3b"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3b3b3b"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:background="#3b3b3b"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20dip"
         />

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#3b3b3b"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Response"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My application crash when I would launch the activity :(

```
11-22 16:10:08.036: E/AndroidRuntime(675): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 16:10:08.036: E/AndroidRuntime(675): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lgc/com.example.lgc.MyActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.webkit.WebView
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: Please post your Java code also

Comment: are you doing this? EditText btnSend = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.web);

Comment: no tags in subject: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles